# Why React.memo and shouldComponentUpdate aren't doing the same?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a functional component which has has a connection to an object in my Redux store. To avoid re-renders when the object has changed I added `React.memo`, however, this didn't avoid the re-renders. My Memo looks something like this:

```
const MemoizedRadio = React.memo(Radio, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  if (prevProps.selected !== nextProps.selected) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  nodes: state.canvas.elements.nodes
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MemoizedRadio);
```

I would expect this component to not re-render if the `nodes` object has changed, but it does.

When I rewrite my component to a class component and add a shouldComponentUpdate the re-render will be prevented as expected. The shouldComponentUpdate looks as followed:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.selected !== nextProps.selected) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

I thought that `React.memo` acted the same as `shouldComponentUpdate` but this does not seem to be the case. The `React.memo` implementation does always re-render when the reference to the `nodes` object changes while the `shouldComponentUpdate` implementation prevents the re-render as expected.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Quick tip: `return prevProps.selected !== nextProps.selected` is already a boolean!

Comment: hmm this all seems fine at a glance, why isn't `selected` part of the props? Also, just out of curiosity, but why would you pass `nodes` as props but aren't interested in re-rendering if they change?

Comment: @James This was just to show some easy example code. I'm rendering a canvas which contains a lot of nodes. Each node can also have children, which are different nodes. The node has a child property which is just the id of the child node. So, to populate the content in the childNode I need to access all my nodes and populate the content with the correct values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `React.memo` correctly, the problem is that you are using `connect` an HOC to connect class based components to the store. Instead of using HOC you should use `useDispatch` and `useSelector`

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna upgrade react-redux to make it work with hooks and see if that helps.